# Cant get value from url- it is not set

Tags: php

This is my page url - `http://linktowebpage.com/edit-page/?dish_id=108`

And this is my php code:

```
if (isset($_POST["dish_id"]))
    echo $_POST["dish_id"];
else
    echo 'dish_id is not set';
```

Why i cant get value of dish_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST` contains post variables. `$_GET` contains variables from the URL's query string.

An encompassing array is `$_REQUEST` that contains both `$_GET` and `$_POST` key=>values.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["dish_id"]))
    echo $_REQUEST["dish_id"];
else
    echo 'dish_id is not set';
```

Answer (score 1):

dish_id in that case would be a GET variable, not a POST variable.  Use $_GET instead of $_POST.

Example:

```
if (isset($_GET["dish_id"]))
    echo $_GET["dish_id"];
else
    echo 'dish_id is not set';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting values from url. You should use `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`

```
if (isset($_GET["dish_id"]))
    echo $_GET["dish_id"];
else
    echo 'dish_id is not set';
```